# What is going wrong when Mountain Lion download does not start?

Tags: macos

I purchased Mountain Lion on App Store and start downloading. It shows an icon the the task bar and a progress bar on the Mountain Lion logo.

But it just doesn't start download. It has been one hour since it started but the progress bar is still empty.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Check the Purchased tab of the App Store.  Any activity there under the OS X Mountain Lion entry?

Comment: Do you have a slow internet connection? Are you using GoogleDNS or OpenDNS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that come to mind:

1. The store is so busy that it's not sending the data to your computer to start the download.
2. The usual things have failed and you can jump start it by following some steps on troubleshooting an App Store download.

Here are the self help steps:

- [Mac App Store: How to resume interrupted downloads](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4485)

Comment: you're probably right that it's busy. It just so slow that almost not downloading. Now I see I have 20 hours left...

Answer (score 1):

From reading elsewhere, the solution for me was to go to my "Purchases" section in the AppStore and select "Download" from there. I don't have the Mountain Lion icon, but I can track the download process from App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here, i started the download last night at about 9 uk time, just got on the computer to check and its still not responding.
Ive tried the a dive from above but its not really done anything,

Update, I've spoken to Apple and they say its because I'm a bt business broadband user, I've also spoken to Bt and its true for me that my business hub only allows a 2 gb download. So now i have to wait for a new hub to arrive... Brill
so if your a bt business user this sounds more likely to be this issue.
Hope this helps

Comment: I ran in to the same problem. You just have to wait. i think it's too busy.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles across this- I was having the same problem- it was downloading between 0 and 20KBps (after 3 days, it had downloaded almost 2GB).

But thanks to Gerry's question about OpenDNS or GoogleDNS, I tried disabling OpenDNS and it is now downloading at a solid 920KBps (The absolute maximum my internet connection provides).

Thanks Gerry!